# SQL: Inserting Row partly from other tables with VALUES option

Tags: sql, insert

I have an issue with my SQL and would be greatly appreciate for some help.

I am trying to `INSERT into table1` whilst Taking Data from one column out of 2 Tables EG:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Data1, Data2)
VALUES(Table2.Data1, Table3.Data2)
```

However this is apart of a form where other data shall be added EG:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (UserID, Data1, Data2, TodayDate)
VALUES(users.UID, Table2.Data1, Table3.Data2, getdate())
```

I have tried so many variations of this and I cant figure it out.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`

Comment: I have tried this and it works for one item but now multple

Answer (score 0):

You should create join query to insert seperated data in other tables like this;

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Data1, Data2)
SELECT t2.Data1, t3.Data2 from Table2 t2 inner join Table3 t3 ON
t2.Id = t3.table2_Id
```

Comment: So would I be able to use the VALUES option after this as I need to use data from my form ???

Comment: You can't VALUES if you want to insert data from other tables. You should select them to insert.

Comment: How do you mean... this is what I need inserted... INSERT INTO work(UserID, WorkDate, WeekNum, HourRate, TimeIn, ) and The TimeIn is being added from a form same as date but everything else is coming out of 2 Tables... There must be a way to use the data from my form and put that in aswell

Comment: You should set default values or select them too for other fields like INSERT INTO Table1 (Data1, Data2, data3, data4)
SELECT t2.Data1, t3.Data2, 'sampledata', 'sampleData' from Table2 t2 inner join Table3 t3 ON
t2.Id = t3.table2_Id

Comment: Sorry But i well dont get it :/ what is this about : Table3 t3 ON t2.Id = t3.table2_Id

Comment: I just provided sample join query. I don't know anything about relationship of your tables. You didn't provide detail for it. Please read this post first; https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: So I am taking it there is no way to insert date and time whilst doing this :/